# find file on/with tree

Tags: tree

I really like [tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree), however would like to combine it with something like find... in particular, I would like to be able to pass to it (or a similar script) as a parameter some file to find
e.g. `*.c` so that it only prints files that end in .c and the path that leads to them.

So if
e.g. we have `tree` returning:

```
.
├── bar
│   ├── b.c
│   └── c.py
└── foo
    └── a.py
```

then `tree -find "*".c` should return

```
.
└── bar
    └── b.c
```

Is there a parameter that would allow this with `tree`? If not, how could this be achieved?

Comment: Use `tree -P *.c`, find more with `man tree`.

Comment: Thnx, I seem to be blind... :) was looking for name at the man page, but its -P for pattern...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case you describe, that can be achieved with the `tree` command's own pattern matching options. Ex. given

```
$ tree dir
dir
├── bar
│   ├── b.c
│   └── c.py
└── foo
    └── a.py

2 directories, 3 files
```

then

```
$ tree -P '*.c' --prune dir
dir
└── bar
    └── b.c

1 directory, 1 file
```

Note the quoting of pattern `'*.c'` to prevent the shell from possibly expanding it to a list of matching files in the current directory.